# Why is there a contradiction in the output by two programs written below (Unions in C)?

Tags: c, data-structures, structure, unions

Here goes the first code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
 union var{
 int a;
 int b;
 };

 union var v;

 v.b=10;
 v.a=5;
 printf("%d", v.b);
 return 0;
}
```

This gives 5 as the output.

However, consider this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
 union var{
 int a;
 float b;
 };

 union var v;

 v.b=10.0;
 v.a=5;

 printf("%f", v.b);

 return 0;

}
```

This gives 0.000000 as the output.

Any explanations?

Comment: There's not much point in having two members with the same type in a union. The whole point is to have a variable that can hold values of different types.

Comment: `v.b` wasn't zero, just very low. If you print with `%g` instead of `%f` you will probably see something.

Comment: In the second example, the crux of the issue is the integer representation of `5` last stored in `v.a` does not provide a valid IEEE-754 Single-Precision Floating-Point value. A `float` is represented `1`-sign bit, `8`-biased exponent bits and a `23`-bit mantissa. The representation of `5` in memory provides bits for an invalid exponent with the sign-bit and mantissa bits all zero -- corresponding to a float value of `0.0` (all mantissa bits zero is the special case for `0`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you please explain in little simpler terms?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What I mean is why are all the bits zero, as you are saying?

Comment: No, the bits in memory will be `00000101000000000000000000000000` (integer `5` in Little Endian). For `float` Bit 31 is the *sign-bit*, Bits 23-30 are the *biased exponent* and bits 0-22 are the *mantissa*. Bits 0-22 are all `0` so the value for the float is defined as `0.0` which is what is output. The reason it is output is you are attempting to print the bits that make up `int` `5` as a `float` -- won't work. Recall a `union` only has storage for the last value stored. Since the last value stored was `int`, the `union` contains an `int` value -- not a `float`.

Comment: @GirikGarg - you can output the bits of `v` when it contains the `int` value `5` and the `float` value `10.` to see the bit values. Here is a [short example program](https://paste.opensuse.org/30953433). You output the bits as an unsigned value in both cases.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: IEEE-754 binary32 does not have any invalid exponent codes. The all-zero exponent indicates a subnormal value. The value represented by bits 00000000000000000000000000000101 is 5•2^−149. The exponent field is zero, and the significand field is 000000000000000000101, not zero. Also, commonly, the bytes of a `float` are stored in the same order as the bytes of an `int`, so endianness is irrelevant. Even if they were not, the result would still be a valid binary32 value.

Comment: Thank you @EricPostpischil - that is borne out by dumping the bits. The Little Endian representation is where that went off track. The bits are `00000000-00000000-00000000-00000101` So at `5•2^−149` it's only out of range by a power of `111`. No question it is a valid 32-bit value -- just not a valid `float`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, thank you. FWIW, however, the caveat remains that the bits "*might be a trap representation*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bits in memory are used to represent different types in different ways. This answer discusses the representations used most commonly for `int` (32-bit two’s complement) and `float` (IEEE-754 binary32, also called single precision), assuming there are no complications with padding bits or different ordering of bits and bytes between `int` and `float`.

For `int`, there is a sign bit and 31 value bits. The 31 value bits are interpreted as a binary numeral. The sign bit represents the value −2<sup>31</sup>, and the value represented by the `int` is the sum of the value of the sign bit and the value of the binary numeral.

When you store 5 in the `int` member `v.a`, 5 is represented with the sign bit 0 and value bits 0000000000000000000000000000101. When you read it with `int` member `v.b`, the bits are interpreted in the same way they were used to represent 5, so the result is 5.

When you read it with `float` member `v.b`, the bits are reinterpreted using the scheme for `float`.

For `float`, there is a sign bit *s*, 8 exponent bits *e*, and 23 significand bits *f*, where *e* and *f* are the values of the bits when interpreted as binary numerals. These bits are interpreted as:

- If *e* = 0, the value represented is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•2<sup>1-127</sup>•(0+*f*/2<sup>23</sup>).
- If 0 < *e* < 255, the value represented is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•2<sup>*e*-127</sup>•(1+*f*/2<sup>23</sup>).
- If *e* = 255 and *f* = 0, the value represented is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•∞.
- If *e* = 255 and *f* ≠ 0, the value represented is a special Not-a-Number (NaN) value. (If the first bit of *f* is set, 2<sup>22</sup> ≤ *f*, it is a quiet NaN. Otherwise, it is a signaling NaN.)

When the bits 00000000000000000000000000000101 are interpreted as a `float`, then *s* is 0, *e* is 0, and *f* is 5. This fits the first condition, so the value represented is (−1)<sup>0</sup>•2<sup>1-127</sup>•(0+5/2<sup>23</sup>) = 2<sup>−126</sup>•5•2<sup>−23</sup> = 5•2<sup>−149</sup>, which is approximately 7•10<sup>−45</sup>.

When you print this number with `%f`, it is so small that only “0.000000” is printed. If you print it with `%g`, the output will be “7.00649e-45”.

Note that, in C, reading the value of a member other than the last one written reinterprets the bytes of memory as the new type, per C 2018 6.5.2.3 3 and note 99. In C++, the behavior is not defined.